# Have apt-get install packages from a specific location

Tags: ubuntu, directory, dependencies, apt-get

I have a bunch of .deb packages that I would like to install. I want to keep them within a specific folder so that I can easily access them. There are about 200 packages in total that all depend on each other. So, can I use apt-get to install this program from a specific folder? In other words, I want to add this folder to the apt-get list so that it will search that folder when looking for the packages to install.

I'm using ubuntu

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can install a webserver on your system like apache or nginx (smaller and maybe more suited for something as simple as this) and create a packages directory in there.

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

The default content dir should be:

```
/usr/share/nginx/html
```

Create create some folders for specific architectures or just for the one you use (amd64 for 64 bit or i386)

```
/urs/share/nginx/html/debs/amd64
```

You can throw all your packages in there and start the server with

```
sudo service nginx start
```

Then create a package list (open a terminal and move to you debs folder) by running this.

```
dpkg-scanpackages amd64 | gzip -9c > amd64/Packages.gz
```

Now add the repository to the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file this can be done manually,

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

add

```
deb http://localhost/debs/ amd64/
```

to the bottom then just run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And you should be able to install from your repository.

Comment: when I type in "sudo apt-get update" I get this message: Get:1 http://localhost share Release.gpg [151 B]
Get:2 http://localhost share Release [151 B]                                   
Ign http://localhost share Release                                             
E: GPG error: http://localhost share Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2

Comment: I changed a few things and now its saying this: E: Malformed line 61 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: I don't get the second warning you described but something else, I assumed that was just because I only put empty files (and no real packages) in the repository. I'll look into it.

Comment: yeah i'm not too familiar with any of this. So anything you find out I'd greatly appreciate it!